# Subtracting arbitrary large integers in C

Tags: c, arrays

**Question:**

- I want to know the difference of number n and a, both stored in char
  arrays in ALI structures. Basically, what I'm doing is initialising
  two integers (temp_n and temp_a) with the current digits of n and a,
  subtracting them and placing the result in a new ALI instance named
  k. If the j-th digits of a is greater than the i-th digit of n, then
  I add 10 to the digit if n, finish the subtraction, and in the next
  turn, I increase temp_a by one. The value of number a certainly falls
  between 1 and n - 1 (that's given). If a is shorter than n, as soon
  as I reach the last digits of a, I put the remaining digits of n to
  the result array k. And I do this all backwards, so the initialising
  value of i would be the size of n -1.

**Example:**

- I store a number in a structure like this:

  ```
  typedef struct Arbitrary_Large_Integer
  {
       char digits[];
  } ALI;
  ```

**Requirements:**

- I know that it could be easier to use char arrays instead of a
  structure with a single member which barely makes sense, but I'm
  forced to put structures in my code this time (that's a requirement
  for my assignment).

---

**Code:**

```
ALI *subtraction(ALI n, ALI a, int nLength, int aLength)
{
    ALI *result;
    result = (ALI*)malloc(nLength * sizeof(ALI));
    if (result == NULL)
    printf("ERROR");

    int temp_n, temp_a, difference; 
    int i = nLength - 1; //iterator for number 'n'
    int j = aLength - 1; //iterator for number 'a'
    int k = 0; //iterator for number 'k', n - a = k
    bool carry = false; //to decide whether a carry is needed or not the turn

    for (i; i >= 0; i--)
    {
         //subtracting 48 from n.digits[i], so temp_n gets the actual number 
         //and not its ASCII code when the value is passed
         temp_n = n.digits[i] - ASCIICONVERT; 
         temp_a = a.digits[j] - ASCIICONVERT;

        //Performing subtraction the same way as it's used on paper
        if (carry) //if there is carry, a needs to be increased by one
       {
              temp_a++;
              carry = false;
        }
              if (temp_n >= temp_a)
              {
                   difference = temp_n - temp_a;
               }
              //I wrote else if instead of else so I can clearly see the condition
             else if (temp_a > temp_n) 
            {
                 temp_n += 10;
                 difference = temp_n - temp_a;
                 carry = true;
            }

            //placing the difference in array k, but first converting it back to ASCII
            result->digits[k] = difference + ASCIICONVERT; 
            k++;

           //n is certainly longer than a, so after every subtraction is performed on a's digits,
           //I place the remaining digits of n in k
           if (j == 0) 
           {
                for (int l = i - 1; l >= 0; l--)
               {
                    result->digits[k] = n.digits[l];
                    k++;
                }

            //don't forget to close the array
            result->digits[k] = '\0';
            break;
          }
          j--;
      }

      //reverse the result array
     _strrev(result->digits);
     return result;
}
```

**Output/Error:**

[Output results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nye3c.png)

- It seems like when the array is passed to the function, its value
  changes for some reason. I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your `ALI` arguments are being sliced, because the flexible array's contents are being chopped off.

Comment: Because your arrays may have to grow (e.g. you get carry outs), using `char *digits` (vs. `char digits[]`) inside your struct might be easier to work with. That's along with an element `int digmax` that denotes the number of bytes currently allocated in `digits`.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

**Non-standard C**

The `typedef` is not a valid standard C structure.  The Flexible Array Member(FAM) `.digits` must be accompanied by at least one more prior named member in addition to the flexible array member.  Recommend to put `.nLength` as the first member.

```
// Not standard 
typedef struct Arbitrary_Large_Integer {
   char digits[];
} ALI;
```

**`malloc(0)`??**

Since code is using a non-standard C, watch out that `nLength * sizeof(ALI)` may be the same as `nLength * 0`.

**No room for the null character**

Code is attempting to use `.digits` as a *string* with `_strrev()`, the`mallloc()` is too small by 1, at least.

**Other problems may exist**

A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is useful for  additional fixes/solutions